# React.js "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined"

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I'm trying to export this component from one file to another

```
export default function Form() {
    return (
        <div>
        <form action="./add_product.php">
        <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <label htmlFor="Student">SKU </label>
        <input name="Student" />
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

file that this component is in is called add_product.js 
 I'm trying to export it into file named fns.js 
this is my code in fns.js that tries to import component

```
import Form from './add_product';
ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById("product_form"));
```

both files in one directory, I include CDN links of react and babel in my code but still getting error like "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined" 
what's the solution to fix this?

Comment: add import React from 'react' line at the top of add_product.js file

Comment: it still shows the same error :/ also I thought since I included CDN links in my code importing React manually from react wouldn't be needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The imports will work if you are using [code splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import).

There are articles about the setup using webpack which you can google "react webpack setup".

If you want to use the CDN way, which I also did when I was learning.
The main thing is to add script tags for all the components.

**HTML**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Testing 1 2 3 ...</h2>
    <div id="product_form"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" src="add_product.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="fns.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**fns.js**

```
// import Form from './add_product';

ReactDOM.render(<>
    <h3>React CDN</h3>
    <Form />
</>,
    document.getElementById("product_form"));
```

**add_product.js**

```
// export default 

function Form() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <label htmlFor="Student">SKU </label>
                    <input name="Student" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I hope that helps.